# how to understand some functions of this code

Tags: swift

below are the code. About the button part. Why the `if let` is needed？

```
import SwiftUI

struct descView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data: Activities
    var activity: ActivityItem
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section  {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text(activity.desc)
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Text("How many times completed")
                Text("\(activity.amount)")
                Button("Make complete once") {
                    var newActivity = activity
                    newActivity.amount += 1

                    if let index = data.activities.firstIndex(of: activity) {
                        //The firstIndex(of:) method tells you the index of an element in an array if it exists, or returns nil otherwise.
                        data.activities[index] = newActivity
                    }
                }
            }
    }
        .navigationTitle(activity.name)
        }   
}
```

I'm a new beginner of swift.Cannot figure out what is the function of below part of code.Could someone explain it? thanks!

```
 if let index = data.activities.firstIndex(of: activity) {
                        //The firstIndex(of:) method tells you the index of an element in an array if it exists, or returns nil otherwise.
                        data.activities[index] = newActivity
```

Comment: Take a look at the Swift docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: `data` looks like it is your data source and with the `if let` part the updated value of newActivity is saved so it will be remembered to the next time you open the view for this specific activity

Comment: essentially the result is the same as `data.activities = data.activities.map { $0 == activity ? newActivity : $0 }`. It finds the index of the activity and then updates it with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure `index` isn't `nil` and/or optional value.

`firstIndex` returns `nil` if the `activity` isn't in `data.activities`

```
activities[index] // does not work if `index` is optional.
```

You can do this several different ways such as using `guard` but the goal is the same when you reach the line that uses `index` make sure it is not `nil`.

Per your comment right now the `Button` is making a copy of the `activity`, changing the copy, and then replacing the list's activity with the updated one.

This is needed because `var activity: ActivityItem` is immutable (cannot change). If you add `@Binding` to the `activity` and make the connection with the list's object in the parent view you can skip this step and alter it directly.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10018

Shows a sample around minute 8

and it would look something like this in your code

```
List($data.activities) { $activity in
    descView(activity: $activity)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.sorry for  not making the question clear. I mean the button's function is to make the amount + 1
`var newActivity = activity
newActivity.amount += 1`
 can do this. why need the part `if let` to find the index.

Comment: @Anna that part is hard to answer with the code you have provided but no `newActivity.amount += 1` would not work because a `struct` is immutable therefore `var activity: ActivityItem` is immutable/cannot change. SwiftUI wrappers allow variables to change so if you add `@Binding` to the variable `var activity: ActivityItem` you would be able to to add without replacing the object.

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10018) video might help right around minute 8. Right now the `Button` is creating a copy, changing it and then replacing the `activity` in the array to compensate for being immutable.

Comment: @Anna I added some code to the answer. If I answered your question can you accept it? it is the green checkmark above

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, variables can be optional and non-optional. When a variable is optional, this means it can be `nil`. If it's non-optional, it is not allowed to be `nil`. To set a variable's type to optional, you add a `?` to the end of the type (e.g. `String?`).

For example:

```swift
var nonOptionalInt: Int = 5
var optionalInt: Int? = 5

optionalInt = nil // Works fine
nonOptionalInt = nil // This will result in an error (and crash)
```

Sometimes, you want to check if an optional variable is `nil` or not before you proceed. In your case, you want to make sure `index` is not `nil`. You want to "unwrap" the optional index (`Int?`) to become a non-optional index (`Int`).

By using `if let` you are unwrapping the variable (via a process called *optional binding*) and if it's not `nil`, you can use it. If it is `nil` you will skip the if block and the code inside will not be executed.

A full example:

```swift
import Foundation

let optionalInt: Int? = 5

print(type(of: optionalInt)) // Prints Optional<Int> - At this moment, the content of the optionalInt variable MIGHT be nil

if let unwrappedInt = optionalInt { // If optionalInt is NOT nil, this statement will be true and I enter the if-block
    print(unwrappedInt) // Prints 5 - Now I know for sure that unwrappedInt is not nil
    print(type(of: unwrappedInt)) // Prints Int - Not optional anymore
}

let anotherOptionalInt: Int? = nil

if let unwrappedInt = anotherOptionalInt { // If optionalInt is NOT nil, this statement will be true and I enter the if-block
    print(unwrappedInt) // This won't be printed
} else {
    print("anotherOptionalInt was nil!") // This will print
}
```

Please note that you can just use the same variable name `if let optionalInt = optionalInt { .. }`, and the `optionalInt` inside the if-block's scope will be a non-optional `Int`. The `optionalInt` outside the if-block will remain the optional `Int?`.

Check this page more information on [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) in Swift.